# Call PHP program with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP program for counting user banner clicks. My banner link is something like this:

```
<a href="<?=$banner_url;?>" onclick="banner_click_count('<?=$banner_id;?>')"><img src=...>
```

When user clicks on image, it runs `banner_click_count()` function with `$banner_id` as parameter.

```
function banner_click_count($ban_id)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'banner_click.php',
   data: {banner_id: $ban_id}
   });

}
```

At **banner_click.php**, I get the **banner_id** with `$banner_id = $_GET['banner_id']);`, search the database based on it. Find the record, then add 1 to **banner_count** column field. After that, redirect to **banner_url**.

When I run the program, I get  `Parse error: parse error, expecting T_VARIABLE' or '$''` on line `$.ajax({`

Addendum: the error is cleared with all your help, but when I click on the link it redirects to **banner_url** directly and does not run the AJAX function.

Addendum:I put the alert("hello"); at the top of ajax function and i got it. So it goes into function

Comment: function banner_click_count is javascript function, it should be in `<script>` element or in '.js' file

Comment: banner_click_count is your javascript function ?

Comment: You cannot have JS code as PHP code. They're two completely different languages.

Comment: yes it is javascript function

Comment: using `$.ajax({` suppose you've have jQuery lib, do you?

Comment: @clickmeplease, put `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>` into your <head></head> in html file;

Comment: I put **JsHttpRequest.js** and **jsencode.js** into header

Comment: @clickmeplease - are you getting errors in your JS console? What are you using to watch your AJAX requests - e.g. Firefox+Firebug? Is the request being kicked off correctly? You may need to finish your `onclick` with `return false;` to ensure the link is not followed (and bear in mind this is not the best way to attach events in jQuery anyway).

Comment: @clickmeplease - what are "JsHttpRequest.js" and "jsencode.js"? Can you link to where you got them from? (ted is right as far as I can tell - you need jQuery).

Comment: I already put **jquery-1.4.4.min.js** at the head.
I have firefox with no firebug

Comment: I added `return false;` at the end. but still no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks to all.

```
function banner_click_count(ban_id)
{
  $.post(
  "banner_click.php",
  {
  banner_id: ban_id
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.You need to put your javascript function under `<script>` tag

2.you need to pass `json string as post data`

3.though you are passing your data as post so you will get this data in php `as $_POST not $_GET`

So change your function as below

```
<script>
function banner_click_count(ban_id)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'banner_click.php',
   data: {banner_id: ban_id}
   });

}
</script>

// in your php use as below
echo $_POST['banner_id']
```

Comment: about the `2`: Javascript allows using `$variables`; `3`: may be a hash

Comment: Ok, the error is cleared, but when i click on the link it redirect to **banner_url** directly and does not run ajax function.

Comment: put alert('hello'); at start of function. see you are getting alert or not ?? and also check in firebug whether you have included jquery or error or any other javascript error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure banner_id is in quotes and that you are including JQuery in your page.
And don't forget a success/error return.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'banner_click.php',
   data: {'banner_id': $ban_id},
   success: function(s) { 
     console.log('success' + s);
   },
   error: function(e) {
     console.log('error' + e);
   }
});
```

Comment: Question: do you know how to reach your console?

Answer (score 0):

Don't we need a `return false` before the function ends?

Comment: It still runs without a return however horrid that might be.

Comment: I added `return false;` at the end. but still no result.

Comment: You could go in the Networks option on your console if you are using Chrome and check if any errors are to be seen in the php which you called through ajax. Many a times it helps.